# Syncing between session storage and ngrx store with feature modules

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm using `ngrx-store-localstorage` npm package to sync my ngrx store with browser session storage.
I have divided my store into chunks using the feature stores
syncing happens perfectly till you refresh the browser; when you refresh the browser, store is recreated, and only the current feature store is built and synced with the session storage, even though all the other feature stores are available in session storage.
Is there any settings available to sync the whole session storage to the store ?

Comment: More suitable to ask about this on https://gitter.im/ngrx/platform

Comment: Can you please provide what your localStorageSync config looks like? As Kayzin Lama pointed out, you should just have to provide the storage config option, but also make sure you have the rehydrate option set true.

Answer (score 2):

just add storage: sessionStorage property to LocalStorageConfig

Answer (score 1):

NGRX allows you to create a middleware [Document](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/metareducers).

Developers can think of meta-reducers as hooks into the action->reducer pipeline. Meta-reducers allow developers to pre-process actions before normal reducers are invoked.

```
import merge from 'lodash.merge';
import { StoreModule, ActionReducer, MetaReducer } from '@ngrx/store';
import { reducers } from './reducers';
 
export function storageMetaReducer<S, A extends Action = Action>(reducer: ActionReducer<S, A>) {
      return function(state: S, action: A): S {
        const nextState = reducer(state, action);
        const savedState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('__storage__')) || {};
        merge(nextState, savedState);
        localStorage.setItem('__storage__', nextState)
        return nextState;
      };
    }
    
export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<any>[] = [storageMetaReducer];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers })
  ],
})
```

#### Main difference between localStorage vs sessionStorage

localStorage is persistent between tabs and sessionStorage is per tab.